# How can I identify different Window's Editions in Windows 11 without using the ProductName registry value?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-11, registrykey

I've been working on detecting Windows 11 machines, which I have successfully done by looking at the CurrentBuild registry value for anything above the build 22000+. However, when it comes to determining Windows 11 editions such as Home, Pro, Enterprise, etc. the only thing I can think of is parsing the ProductName registry value and looking for key words that correspond to the Windows 11 editions. I have tried to look through the Registry to find anything resembling 'Windows 11 Home/Pro/Enterprise' but I have not been able to find anything. Has anyone been able to find a registry value that corresponds to the edition other than in the way I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code, you can make use of [GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) assuming you have the proper [manifest](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/) in your EXE.

Alternatively, look at the WMI API using **OperatingSystemSKU** in [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem).

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified in my original post. This is being done using proprietary python software which allows access to the entire Windows registry, so unfortunately I don't believe that will be possible. Once again, sorry about the clarification.

Comment: WMI is much more reliable than reg entries. See [this article](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html).